# How to sync PDF's on Mendeley with iBooks on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf

Is there a way that I can sync PDF files on [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) with the iBooks app on the iPhone. As an alternative is there a way I can sync the files with any PDF reader on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) to [sync the PDF files](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/internet-howto/how-to-use-dropbox-on-your-iphone/) to your iPhone.

- [**Dropbox iPhone App**](https://www.dropbox.com/iphoneapp)

Answer (score 0):

If you can download those PDFs to your computer, just drag them into your iTunes library. The "Books" subsection will be created (if it isn't already) next to Music, Movies, Podcasts, Apps, etc. and then you can sync them to your iPhone quite easily.