# How can I get PDFs onto my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, pdf, ebook

How can I get PDF files onto my iPhone to read? I can't seem to find a way to put your own PDFs into the iBooks application from my computer.

So far, I've been putting them on my google docs account and viewing via safari, but they are quite large PDFs so each time it takes a while to load and can be awkward to work with.

Comment: This question is not accurate and does not fit to SuperUser's FAQ. Please read it! This question might be closed soon. Please use search engines or forum

Comment: I am utterly confused. I can find nothing in this question that I would describe as inaccurate--is your objection simply to the fact that it has to do with the iPhone instead of "computers"? The answer to this question in fact directly involves iTunes, so I would suggest that the iPhone is a peripheral in this particular setting.

Comment: Oh, and http://superuser.com/questions/157053/how-to-sync-pdfs-on-mendeley-with-ibooks-on-the-iphone/168008#168008

Comment: No it's not related. We are talking about iPhone+PDF. We somebody can't open a PDF on a computer for any reasons, then the question is accurate for SU as our FAQ. But, iPhone is a "cell phone" and it has been decided that we do not provide any support for phones, PDA, Smartphones, Blackberry and so on. Hope my explanations are more clear.

Comment: @NR - questions about iPhone (and smartphones in general) are [off-topic](http://superuser.com/faq) on this site, this is what r0ca meant. However, if the question is about interfacing them with the computer, they can be asked here.  About your question, it's true that the answer probably involves a computer, since moreover you want a direct way, not anymore with Google docs. As such, I think it's ok to ask such question here, even if it's a bit of a gray area.

Comment: Note however that we have a new sister site, in public beta, dedicated to [Apple products](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) like the iPhone, where such question would probably be better suited.

Comment: Thanks Gnoupi. I'm french Canadian so sometimes it's hard to explain correctly my thoughts.

Comment: @r0ca - no problem with language. Note however that while it's really appreciated that you make sure the scope of the site is respected, don't forget that the FAQ states "not about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer". As such, this question, is centered on how to do it with a computer, is acceptable for this site. @James - I took the liberty to insist on "with a computer" in your question, to be sure we are in the scope. Feel free to revert if you don't like my change.

Comment: Thanks guys, apologies should have worded question better. I was having trouble finding a way to have them show in iTunes (on my pc), but after reading the blog post I linked below (why downvote? it solved my issue) things are OK. Also an upgrade on iTunes helped as I wasnt able to add ebooks on my previous version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W/ your iPod Touch or iPhone attached, drag the PDF to your iBooks on the device.

Answer (score 1):

When you open pdf from email attachment or from the web, you should see "Open in iBooks"
When you tap it, pdf doc will open in iBooks app and sit there. and when you sync iphone with mac/pc, pdf appears in your ibooks itunes section.

Answer (score 1):

I actually use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) - I just drop anything I want into the dropbox on my PC and then I can read it on the iPhone. Unfortunately, it is till an 'on-line' thing, so you might still have network issues, but I haven't really had a problem with it.

Answer (score -1):

Used this blog post : http://phractalattice.posterous.com/uploading-pdf-docs-to-iphone-without-emailing